# How to detect a large image in PDF and extract it as a JPEG or any format?

Tags: java, android, pdf, ghostscript

I'm creating a project that creates a magazine from PDF file, however each uploaded magazine should have a thump that has a cover photo, and i want to extract this image from the PDF as a JPEG in order to set it as a cover photo.

Is there any way to do it using Ghostscript or any other command line tool ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to render the first page of a PDF file to an image format ? If so then yes, Ghostscript can do that (also ImageMagick using Ghostscript, MuPDF and probably many other utilities too).

If you mean the first page *contains* an image, and you do actually want to extract it, then this is a harder job and you will need a PDF toolkit to do it. Ghostscript *can* do this,but its probably overkill, again you might find MuPDF more convenient. I have a vague memory that pdftk can extract images, but I may be mistaken. A quick search on Google should probably help, if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Poppler/XPDF comes with [`pdfimages`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages):

> Pdfimages saves images from a Portable Document Format (PDF) file as Portable Pixmap (PPM), Portable Bitmap (PBM), or JPEG files.
>   Pdfimages reads the PDF file PDF-file, scans one or more pages, and writes one PPM, PBM, or JPEG file for each image, image-root-nnn.xxx, where nnn is the image number and xxx is the image type (.ppm, .pbm, .jpg).

The commandline to extract all images from page 1 of a PDF is this:

```
pdfimages -j -f 1 -l 1 some.pdf subdir/prefix
```

The images will be saved to `subdir/` named `prefix-0000.jpeg`, `prefix-0001.jpeg`. The **`-j`** parameter will try to get JPEG images, if possible. Direct JPEG extraction may fail, in which case the images extracted will be saved as PPM or PNM (attention, these are big, since they're uncompressed). These can be converted by ImageMagick's to JPEGs, if needed:

```
convert subdir/prefix-0022.ppm subdir/prefix-0022.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

ABCpdf will allow you to extract images from a PDF. It's a two stage operation. First you need to identify where images appear in the document. Then you need to export them.

You need something like this...

```
using (Doc theDoc = new Doc()) {
    theDoc.Read(theSrc);
    ImageOperation op = new ImageOperation(theDoc);
    op.PageContents.AddPages();
    ICollection<ImageProperties> images = op.GetImageProperties();
    foreach (ImageProperties pl in images) {
    foreach (ImageRendition plc in pl.Renditions) {
            ... if plc is a good match
            plc.PixMap.GetBitmap().Save(@"c:\output.jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

I work on the ABCpdf .NET software component so my replies may feature concepts based around ABCpdf. It's just what I know. :-)"